# Flutter web set Cookie is not in response headers, but same available in flutter mobile

Tags: flutter, cookies, setcookie

there is one error that I'm facing so the scenario is this

I'm trying to set the cookies from a backend node js server to flutter web

this is the code for the cookie

```
  res.cookie('something', 'hello there', {
    domain: 'localhost',
    path: '/',
    sameSite: 'None',
    secure: true,
    httpOnly: false,
  });
```

httpOnly is false, so it can be accessed by browser

so on one particular endpoint I'm setting the cookie

and when I run a request

```
     final token = await TokensDB.get();
     final xhr = html.HttpRequest();
     xhr.open('GET', API.communities().toString());
        xhr.setRequestHeader(
            'Authorization', API.header(token.access)['Authorization']);
        xhr.withCredentials = true;

        final completer = Completer<List<Community>>();

        xhr.onLoad.listen((html.ProgressEvent event) async {
          final res = xhr.responseText;
          final headers = xhr.responseHeaders;
          log('these are the headers $headers');
  
          completer.complete([]);
        });

        xhr.onError.listen((event) {
          completer.completeError('Request failed');
        });
```

log('these are the headers $headers');

but on the log 'headers' I **DONT** see the **set-cookie** headers, whereas in the chrome browser I can see the 'Set-Cookie' response header please let me know what I'm doing wrong and how to solve it, and when I run the same code on flutter web I can read the 'Set-Cookie'
from code

[image]

just so you know my flutter web front is running on different domains

and on production the backend is on 'example.mydomain.com' and flutter website is on 'exampleflutterDifferentDomain.com' (front end and backend are on different domains)

Comment: i have the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope, I still haven't :(

Comment: nope not yet, haven't got any clue to solve this issue